# Htaccess - Rewrite engine (reverse engineering a line of code)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

On a site I'm working on, if you enter the url, plus 1 directory, the htaccess adds a trailing slash.

So, this:  `http://www.mysite.com/shirts`

Becomes this:   `http://www.mysite.com/shirts/`

The htaccess that runs the site is quite long and complex, so it's not easy to find or test which rule is causing the rewrite.  I was able to track down the issue to this line of code (I think):

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Does this rule match the behavior I'm describing above?  It seems to be the cause, but it doesn't make logical sense to me.  I don't unsderstand where the trailing slash is coming from.

Can someone shed some light on this for me?  Thanks in advance.

Edit:  MORE:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default apache will add the ending `/`, you will have to use:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

To disable that behavior which is caused by `mod_dir`, [**you can read more about it here.**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash)

However if you're trying to remove the `/` to fix images not showing. That is not the right way to do it, you should instead use the HTML `base` tag, for example:

```
<BASE href="http://www.yourdomain.com/">
```

[**Read more here about it.**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4)

---

Your current rule as you have updated on your question:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Means:

- if domain on the URL is only `mysite.com`
- redirect current URL to domain with `www.`

So an example of it would be, if you access:

```
http://domain.com/blog/some_blog_article
```

It will redirect the user to:

```
http://www.domain.com/blog/some_blog_article
```

Note how it retains everything and only add the `www.` to the domain.

---

If you really want to redirect it regardless here is one way to do it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# check if it is a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# check if the ending `/` is missing and redirect with slash
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# if file or directory does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and we still want to append the `/` at the end
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @Kevin What comes before that line? Is there a RewriteCond before it?

Comment: I'm not actually trying to disable it.  We have links on the site pointing with and without the slash, so I wanted to convert them all to having the slash, then make sure the NON-slash version was being 301 redirected, not just redirected.  Now i dont' know what to do.

Comment: the line before that is:  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/.*

Comment: @Kevin any other RewriteCond comes along with the one u mentioned above or just that one? Because with just these 2 your rule is rather unneeded and ambiguous. If you could update your question with the full rule for readability, it is usually what comes before the RewriteRule in question until the previous RewriteRule.

Comment: sorry, I pasted in the wrong thing....here we go again: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: thanks for the help.  Last question - I think I understand better now.  Since it's standard behavior for the server to add the trailing slash, I don't think I need to worry about the 301 redirect...do you agree?

Comment: You can redirect if you wish but the server will do it automatically given `DirectorySlash` is not off.

Comment: @Kevin if you still wish to add the redirect regardless I've update 2 rules at the bottom.